# Matlab connection error warning

Tags: matlab

Every time I start Matlab I am shown a modal Warning message to alert me to the fact that Matlab couldn't connect to MathWorks. I am searching for a way to stop Matlab from attempting this connection, or at least to disable the message. I work on an offline system, which has no internet access.

[image: Matlab Warning]

I could find two places within the preferences which pertain to internet connectivity, and disabled them both. But the problem persists.

[image: Matlab preference 1]

[image: Matlab preference 2]

I can't seem to find an answer in the MathWorks support pages. Does anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: This is related to your license. You probably have a license type that requires you to be connected to a license server?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I don't think so. It's a standalone license. The software works fine; the popup is just an annoyance.

Comment: I don't see such a dialog box when starting MATLAB without internet connection. 100% of the relevant google results are questions by people that get this message when trying to install MATLAB. This is related to the license. Did you contact The MathWorks?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Agreed on the search results. I have the same license running on another offline machine, and see no problem there. I have not contacted MathWorks; I was hoping for a simple fix here first. Thanks for the feedback.